# Conditional Formatting ( Left )

Tags: excel, formatting

May i know how to do the data bars to the right instead of left? I only know how to do it to the right.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conditional formatting - Manage rules - Click rules that you want to change - Edit rules - Bar direction; Right to Left